# UWP MVVM Sqlite C# - New items added to listview update after page is reloaded

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm

I am trying to implement CRUD functionality to use with a local SQLite database (namespace Microsoft.Data.Sqlite) and following an MVVM pattern ([John Shew’s Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/)).

I encounter an issue where the update functionality does not work on newly added items to the listview. Any new items added to a listview will need to be reloaded before the user can edit their data and have the change update in the database. Items that were previously loaded into the listview can still be edited, and those changes are reflected in the listview and in the database.

I’ve looked into using async/await, Task Async Programming, switching all List<> to ObservableCollections<>, and still not working. I've looked through a lot of posts and now coming to stackoverflow for help.

I’m not sure what code to post, as I only want to provide what’s applicable for diagnosis and not create too much noise/clutter. Please let me know and I will provide.

```
public static void InitializeDatabase()
        {
            using (SqliteConnection db =
                new SqliteConnection("Filename=TestDB.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
            string tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT " +
                "EXISTS Student (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "Name NVARCHAR(2048) NULL," +
                "Email NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";

            SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);
            createTable.ExecuteReader();
            db.Close();
        }
    }
public static void Write(Student student)
        {
            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=TestDB.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand
                {
                    Connection = db,
                    CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student VALUES (NULL, @Name, @Email)"
                };
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", student.Name = "");
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", student.Email = "");
                insertCommand.ExecuteReader();
                db.Close();
            }
        }

public static void Update(Student student)
        {
            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=TestDB.db"))
            {
                db.Open();
                SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand
                {
                    Connection = db,
                    CommandText = "UPDATE Student SET Name=@Name, Email=@Email WHERE Id=@Id";
                };
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ((object)student.Name) ?? DBNull.Value);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", ((object)student.Email) ?? DBNull.Value);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ((object)student.Id) ?? DBNull.Value);
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                db.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the section of code where `Create` and `Update` takes place?

Comment: The code you add is a [mcve]. Copy your project, strip out absolutely everything (even styling attributes) except what is needed to exhibit what you're trying to do ("I've looked into" pick one solid implementation and get it in there) then [edit] that code into your question. Also, be very clear why "it does not work". http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode http://idownvotedbecau.se/itdoesntwork

Comment: "the update functionality does not work on newly added items to the listview." Is it possible that after you've added the item to the database, you did not update the new item with its id before adding it to the listview?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I included code for Create and Update as requested. I also included the code for insert as well. It is possible that I did not update the new items id before adding it to the listview. Can I find that information by stepping through my code with a debugger, or is there a more effective approach?

Comment: @MikeJP Set a breakpoint on `insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ((object)student.Id) ?? DBNull.Value); //from Update()` and try to update an newly created row. When the breakpoint is hit, confirm if the `student.Id` is valid.

Comment: If it does not contains it. Replace `insertCommand.ExecuteReader();` with `student.id = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar(); //in Write()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Xiaoy312. I was finally able to solve this issue by setting a break point on insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ((object)student.Id) ?? DBNull.Value) and observed that the Id was not a valid number, displaying null. I setup some additional breakpoints to follow the Id, tried a few different approaches to get the Id to update and no go. I ended up creating a method to retrieve the Id from the last row, increment it by 1 then insert the new Id into the database. It It is not elegant but functional.